# VBA input data in the Web field

Tags: html, vba, excel, web

I am coding vba to open the central bank's website and input the values ​​and extract the data, I usually do this on the mail site, bank of Brazil etc ...

() of the central bank

```
I can not give the input value via vba in the textbox I've already tried:



Ie.Document.all.Item("valueConverter").Innertext="1"
Ie.Document.getElementById("valueConverter").Value="1"
Ie.Document.getElementById("valueConverter")(0).Value="1"
Ie.Document.getElementByName("valueConverter").Value = "1"
```

The Elements of this site is this:

```
<Input type = "text" name = "valueConverter" maxlength = "17" size "20" value onkeypress = "return (MascaraMoeda (this, '.', ',', Event)
```

Does anyone know how?

Comment: What's the page's URL you are trying to interact with?

Comment: http://www4.bcb.gov.br/pec/conversao/conversao.asp

Comment: I took a look. This control is in an iFrame with security enabled that prevents access via the DOM. Normally you'd access this by `ie.document.GetElementsByTagName("iFrame")(0).ContentDocument` them from here you can select the element. However I'm getting an Access Denied error.

Comment: I have answered this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969316/excel-web-query-submit-issues/50845661#50845661

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr;**

I cannot mark this as a duplicate as there is no accepted answer to where I posted an answer to a similar question.

Not sure of the protocol as simply posting a link in the comments doesn't mean it will be found again.

My full answer is here:  [Excel Web Query Submit Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969316/excel-web-query-submit-issues/50845661#50845661)

---

**To summarize:**

You can use the [bcb.gov.br Open Data Portal](https://dadosabertos.bcb.gov.br/en/).

Send a request for a JSON response with the conversion rates from their Exchange rates – [daily bulletins](https://dadosabertos.bcb.gov.br/en/dataset/exchange-rates-daily-bulletins).

With the received response, amongst other methods, you can then:

1. Use the [JSON Converter](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) .basa and set the convert the response into a JSON object and work with that
2. Parse the response as a string with a regex to get the values

For brevity, I will give you just the second method here and you can view my other answer for both methods:

```
Public Sub GetInfo2()

    Dim strURL As String, strJSON As String, item As Variant, http As Object, json As Object
    Const TARGET_CURRENCY As String = "USD"
    Const START_DATE As String = "06-13-2018"
    Const END_DATE As String = "06-13-2018"

    strURL = "https://olinda.bcb.gov.br/olinda/service/PTAX/version/v1/odata/ExchangeRatePeriod(moeda=@moeda,dataInicial=@dataInicial,dataFinalCotacao=@dataFinalCotacao)?%40moeda=%27" & TARGET_CURRENCY & "%27&%40dataInicial=%27" & START_DATE & "%27&%40dataFinalCotacao=%27" & END_DATE & "%27&%24format=json"

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", strURL, False
    http.send
    strJSON = http.responseText
    Dim Matches As Object
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = """cotacaoCompra"":\d{1,}.\d{1,}"  'The pattern I really wanted, "(?<=""cotacaoCompra"":)\d{1,}.\d{1,}", doesn't appear to be supported

        If Not .test(strJSON) Then Exit Sub
        Set Matches = .Execute(strJSON)

        Dim match As Object
        For Each match In Matches
            Debug.Print Replace(match, """cotacaoCompra"":", vbNullString)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```