# Submit or bypass form for a Web Query

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to get dollar exchange rate from http://www4.bcb.gov.br/pec/taxas/port/ptaxnpesq.asp?id=txcotacao into a Excel spreadsheet.

I tried to paste as refreshable web query, however, the page opens one step earlier with a form, which has default inputs (that work for me) and then the query copies stuff from this page.

I tried to write a code to submit the form. I tried the `.submit`, `.Click`, `.FireEvent` and many other things I found on internet.

I tried to refer to the button by its name, class, tag, ...

```
<input title="Pesquisar" class="botao" onclick="limparVazio()" type="submit" value="Pesquisar">
```

I tried to trigger the form directly or bypass it

```
<form name="consultarBoletimForm" action="/ptax_internet/consultaBoletim.do?method=consultarBoletim" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bcb.gov.br [Open Data Portal](https://dadosabertos.bcb.gov.br/en/).

Send a request for a JSON response with the conversion rates from their [Exchange rates – daily bulletins](https://dadosabertos.bcb.gov.br/en/dataset/exchange-rates-daily-bulletins).

With the received response, amongst other methods, you can then:

1. Use the [JSON Converter](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) and set the convert the response into a JSON object and work with that;
2. Parse the response as a string with a regex to get the values

---

Looking at the results for today's rate on the [site](http://www4.bcb.gov.br/pec/conversao/conversao.asp):

**Input:**

[image: Input]

**Output:**

[image: Rates]

**Result:**

You can see USD 1 = 3,7048 BRL

---

### ① **Using JSON object:**

Example string to make request:

```
"https://olinda.bcb.gov.br/olinda/service/PTAX/version/v1/odata/ExchangeRatePeriod(moeda=@moeda,dataInicial=@dataInicial,dataFinalCotacao=@dataFinalCotacao)?%40moeda=%27" & TARGET_CURRENCY & "%27&%40dataInicial=%27" & START_DATE & "%27&%40dataFinalCotacao=%27" & END_DATE & "%27&%24format=json"
```

I include the start date, end date and currency in the string as well as specify the response format as JSON. I have selected the date to match the website view shown in the images above.

The JSON response is as follows:

[image: JSON response]

I read the response into a string variable and then use `JsonConverter.ParseJson(strJSON)` to convert to a JSON object, stored in `json` variable. A quick inspection of the structure:

[image: JSON structure]

The begining "{" tells me that `json` is a dictionary.

[image: dictionary]

I can also see that `json("value")` is a collection of dictionaries and that the value I am interested in,  `3,7048` - remember from the website images above, is stored as `"cotacaoCompra"`.

I can thus use the following script to access that value. The JSON response actually gives rates at 5 different times on that date in question. These are all printed out. The `Fechamento` (Closing) bulletin rate of 3,7048 we can see matches.

---

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim strURL As String, strJSON As String, item As Variant, http As Object, json As Object
    Const TARGET_CURRENCY As String = "USD"
    Const START_DATE As String = "06-13-2018"
    Const END_DATE As String = "06-13-2018"

    strURL = "https://olinda.bcb.gov.br/olinda/service/PTAX/version/v1/odata/ExchangeRatePeriod(moeda=@moeda,dataInicial=@dataInicial,dataFinalCotacao=@dataFinalCotacao)?%40moeda=%27" & TARGET_CURRENCY & "%27&%40dataInicial=%27" & START_DATE & "%27&%40dataFinalCotacao=%27" & END_DATE & "%27&%24format=json"

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", strURL, False
    http.send
    strJSON = http.responseText
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strJSON)

    For Each item In json("value")
        Debug.Print "rate " & item("cotacaoCompra") & " at " & item("dataHoraCotacao")
    Next item
End Sub
```

**Script output:**

[image: Script output]

---

**Notes:**

Requires JSONConverter bas added and VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting RunTime)

---

### ② **Parsing the responseText with a regex to get the rates:**

The regex I will use is

```
"cotacaoCompra":\d{1,}.\d{1,}
```

This looks for the literal string  `"cotacaoCompra":`, followed by 1 or more numbers then a ".", then one of more numbers.

[image: Example matches]

I then have to remove the string `"cotacaoCompra":` with a straight forward replace. Ideally, I would just extract the numbers with `"(?<=""cotacaoCompra"":)\d{1,}.\d{1,}"`; basically, that says after, but not including `"cotacaoCompra":`. But that doesn't appear to be supported.

With that in mind the script to get the rates with regex:

**Code:**

```
Public Sub GetInfo2()

    Dim strURL As String, strJSON As String, item As Variant, http As Object, json As Object
    Const TARGET_CURRENCY As String = "USD"
    Const START_DATE As String = "06-13-2018"
    Const END_DATE As String = "06-13-2018"

    strURL = "https://olinda.bcb.gov.br/olinda/service/PTAX/version/v1/odata/ExchangeRatePeriod(moeda=@moeda,dataInicial=@dataInicial,dataFinalCotacao=@dataFinalCotacao)?%40moeda=%27" & TARGET_CURRENCY & "%27&%40dataInicial=%27" & START_DATE & "%27&%40dataFinalCotacao=%27" & END_DATE & "%27&%24format=json"

    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", strURL, False
    http.send
    strJSON = http.responseText
    Dim Matches As Object
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = """cotacaoCompra"":\d{1,}.\d{1,}"  'The pattern I really wanted, "(?<=""cotacaoCompra"":)\d{1,}.\d{1,}", doesn't appear to be supported

        If Not .test(strJSON) Then Exit Sub
        Set Matches = .Execute(strJSON)

        Dim match As Object
        For Each match In Matches
            Debug.Print Replace(match, """cotacaoCompra"":", vbNullString)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```